# php replacement for safe_mode

Tags: php, curl

i am new to learning PHP and so I've installed the latest version (5.3.3) and am writing some code. i have run across this error:

> PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in C:\Rush\dev\personal\Numina.Framework\Development\PHP Library\Numina.Framework\clsHttpUtil.php on line 47

When I look up the documentation for safe_mode it tells me that it is deprecated. why was it deprecated and what can i do to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`safe_mode` had good intentions, but was implemented unevenly.  It was deprecated because it caused more problems than it solved, and was not a general security solution.  There are better ways to achieve application environment protection now (like FastCGI, suexec, chroots, jails, VPSes...)

You can fix your error by turning `safe_mode` off, and design your code not to assume that it's being used *or disused*.  **Please note that `safe_mode` has been *removed* as of PHP 5.4.0.**

---

Here's [more information on why `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` was disabled](http://au.php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-setopt.php#71313) when `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` are in effect.  Problems like this are one of the main reasons why `safe_mode` is likely to be removed from PHP entirely.