# Worked and than stopped working... CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled -

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have just written a code which has worked well. It has got the data with CURL, I have run the .php file 2x times, but for the 3rd time I got this message all over the site: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in`

I have NOT changed anything. What could be the problem? So it has worked well, than stopped working...

Comment: Do you host this site, or is it hosted elsewhere? Someone might have changed a config somewhere.

Comment: I'm hosting the site. Btw to be honest I have changed these in the php:Max Execution Time :100 Max Input Time : 100
But than I have changed them back and restarted the server. And still the same problem :(

Comment: Is `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` enabled in `php.ini`?

Comment: Safe mode is off and: ;open_basedir =

This is what I have.

Comment: Is it possibly redirecting to a URL that is a `file://`?

Comment: nope, its something like:  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://***.com/api-get.php?$post_data");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Comment: possible duplicate of [CURLOPT\_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918623/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated) AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349280/php-replacement-for-safe-mode